# Naming convention for Redux actions to differentiate requests and model updates

Tags: redux

Let's say my Redux global state looks as follows:

```
{
    micEnabled    : Boolean,
    filterEnabled : Boolean
}
```

A React component has a "Enable Mic" button that, upon clicked, should perform an async operation (that may take a while) and resolves with a Promise. In order to run such an async operation I can add a custom Redux middleware into the store, or can use `redux-thunk`, etc. That's not the question.

Here my question: Which one should be the name of the Redux action invoked on "Enable Mic" click?

When there is no async stuff involved it's common to name Redux actions as "setters" (`SET_CURRENT_TIME`) or expressive actions (`TOGGLE_FILTER`) that will be directly used by reducers to update state. So one may suggest `ENABLE_MIC` for my use case above, but the fact is that such an action (let's say "action 1") should not directly update `state.micEnabled`.

Instead, my Redux middleware will intercept action 1 (`ENABLE_MIC`), run the async operation and, once resolved, dispatch yet another Redux action ("action 2") so the corresponding reducer would update `state.micEnabled`. So "action 2" could be `MIC_ENABLED`.

To summarize:

- Click on button dispatches `ENABLE_MIC`.
- Redux middleware intercepts it and performs async operation.
- On resolved, middleware dispatches `MIC_ENABLED`.
- Reducer updates `state.micEnabled`.

Ok, this makes lot of sense. The problem is that, within my actions, I also have tons of "common actions" that are dispatched to reducers to update state (such as `TOGGLE_FILTER`):

- Click on checkbox dispatches `TOGGLE_FILTER`.
- Reducer updates `state.filterEnabled`.

So both `ENABLE_MIC` and `TOGGLE_FILTER` represent "commands" or "requests", but just one of them (`TOGGLE_FILTER`) is used by reducers to update state. In the other side, the reducer also listens for `MIC_ENABLED` action (which is not a "command" or "request" but something that has happened or an event).

So, is there any recommendation for naming these kinds of Redux actions in a comprehensible so, by looking at the name of all my Redux actions, I can easily know which ones update state and which ones just dispatch another actions?

Comment: OK, I'm going for the following approach: Split `actionCreators.js` into `requestActions.js` and `stateActions.js`."Request actions" ARE NOT handled by reducers. Instead they do some API stuff and, eventually, may dispatch "state actions". "State actions" do not async stuff at all but are just handled by reducers to update Redux state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it like an AJAX request and call them `ENABLE_MIC_REQUEST` which can result in `ENABLE_MIC_SUCCESS` or `ENABLE_MIC_FAILURE` (if this is possible in your scenario). You could cover everything in one action creator, using thunk, named something like `enableMic`. That should be fairly transparent.

Only `ENABLE_MIC_SUCCESS` would then flip `micEnabled` in the reducer. I'd recommend to rename that to `isMicEnabled` btw to make it super clear that it's a boolean flag.

When handling `ENABLE_MIC_FAILURE` you can show error messages, or do whatever is appropriate in your app.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's quite similar to what I've figured out: having explicit verbs in action names. In my case I've chosen `MUTE_MIC` and `UNMUTE_MIC` request actions, and `SET_MIC_MUTED` / `SET_MIC_UNMUTED` as actions handled by reducers.

Comment: To clarify: all the actions that should be just handled by reducers have a name like `ADD_XXXX`, `REMOVE_XXXX` or `SET_XXXX_YYYY`. In the other side, actions that must be just handled by Redux middlewares (including redux-thunk) have a name like `ENABLE_XXXX`, `CHANGE_XXXXX`, `CREATE_XXXX`, `CLOSE_XXXX`, etc.